# Get number of nodes at each relationship depth

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working on a project where each user is represented as a node in Neo4j. Users can 'endorse' other users, creating a relationship. I want to be able to rank users based on their trust, where the weighting of each relationship is based on the weighting of the user which endorsed them. For example, a user who has been endorsed by 20+ users should have more weighting to their own endorsements than another user with only a couple of endorsements.

The way I'm querying it at the moment gives me the number of nodes for each depth, but it doesn't group by the parent node (e.g. all level 3 nodes are returned in one array, you don't know which nodes from level 2 each relates to).

```
MATCH (n)-[r:TRUSTS*]->(u)
WHERE u.name = 'XYZ' WITH n.name AS n, LENGTH(r) AS depth
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT n) AS endorsers, depth
ORDER BY depth
```

Here's what the network looks like, along with the result of a query for Ben.

[image]
[image]

As you can see, there are 2 first-level endorsers of `Ben`, and two 2nd-level endorsers of `JM`, which you can see from the graph image, but not from the query result.

Can anyone advise on either how to return the results grouped by parent node AND depth, so I can calculate the trust ranking in my code, or a better way to perform a weighted average to achieve the goal in the first paragraph?

This is an example of the sort of tree structure output I'm imagining for Ben:

```
Ben
├── JM
│   ├── Simon
│   └── Rus
│       ├── Robbie
│       │   ├── Ben
│       │   │   └──/ should terminate here
│       │   ├── Simon
│       │   └── JM
│       └── Ben
│           └──/ should terminate here
└── Simon
```

Here is another one for Rus:

```
Rus
├── Robbie
│   ├── Simon
│   ├── Ben
│   │   ├── Simon
│   │   └── JM
│   │       ├── Simon
│   │       └── Rus
│   └── JM  
│       ├── Simon
│       └── Rus            
└── Ben
    ├── Simon
    └── JM
        ├── Simon
        └── Rus
```

Obviously it should terminate when it reaches the user I'm querying for (otherwise it would be a circular structure).

---

The closest match I've found is a query provided by Tezra, which is:

```
MATCH (target:User{name:"Rus"}), (person:User), p=((person)-[:TRUSTS*]->(target))
WHERE ALL(n in NODES(p)[1..-1] WHERE n<>target)
RETURN NODES(p)[-2].name as endorser, COLLECT(person.name) as endorsed_by, SIZE(RELATIONSHIPS(p)) as depth
ORDER BY depth
```

This query returns the 1st level endorsers of "Rus", then the n-level endorsers 1st level endorsers:

```
| endorser | endorsed_by           | depth |
|----------|-----------------------|-------|
| Robbie   | Robbie                | 1     | // 1st level endorsers of Rus
| Ben      | Ben                   | 1     | // 1st level endorsers of Rus

| Robbie   | JM, Simon, Ben        | 2     | // 1st level endorsers of Robbie
| Ben      | JM, Simon             | 2     | // 1st level endorsers of Ben

| Ben      | Rus, Simon            | 3     | // 2nd level endorsers of Ben
| Robbie   | Rus, Simon, JM, Simon | 3     | // 2nd level endorsers of Robbie

| Robbie   | Rus, Simon            | 4     | // 3rd level endorsers of Robbie
```

This isn't quite correct, you only know who has indirectly endorsed Ben and Robbie, but not the nodes in between.

For example, from that output we know that the 1st level endorsers of `Robbie` are `JM`, `Simon` and `Ben`. The 2nd level endorsers are `Rus`, `Simon`, `JM` and `Simon` (column 4 in the tree), however there is no way to know the relationship between the 1st and 2nd level endorsers. As far as this query is concerned, the following trees are identical:

```
Rus
└── Robbie
    ├── Simon
    ├── Ben         <--- here Ben has 3 children (so should be weighted higher)
    │   ├── Simon
    │   ├── Rus
    │   └── JM
    └── JM
        └── Simon 


Rus
└── Robbie
    ├── Simon
    ├── Ben
    │   └── Simon
    └── JM          <--- here JM has 3 children instead
        ├── Simon     
        ├── Rus
        └── JM
```

What I'm looking for is a query which returns something like this (with the parent of each endorsement so the full tree can be reconstructed), this is the imagined output for Rus:

```
+--------+----------+-------+
| parent | children | depth |
+--------+----------+-------+
| Rus    | Robbie   | 1     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| Rus    | Ben      | 1     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| Robbie | Simon    | 2     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| Robbie | Ben      | 2     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| Robbie | JM       | 2     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| Ben    | Simon    | 3     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| Ben    | JM       | 3     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| JM     | Simon    | 4     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| JM     | Rus      | 4     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| JM     | Simon    | 3     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| JM     | Rus      | 3     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| Ben    | Simon    | 2     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| Ben    | JM       | 2     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| JM     | Simon    | 3     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| JM     | Rus      | 3     |
+--------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: The two first-level endorsers of Ben are JM and Simon, right? But which are the 2nd-level endorsers of JM?

Comment: Robbie and Ben, right.

Comment: By your description I think you are trying to make another column in the output called parent (or parents). If true, what should be the exact content of this column for each line in the image shown in your question?

Comment: @BrunoPeres I've added an example of the sort of output I'd expect

Comment: Take a look in this query and see if it can help you in some way: `MATCH (parent)-[:TRUSTS*0..1]->(n)-[r:TRUSTS*]->(u)
WHERE u.name = 'JM'
WITH collect(distinct parent.name) AS parent, collect(DISTINCT n.name) AS n, LENGTH(r) AS depth
RETURN parent, n, depth
ORDER BY depth`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here is a [console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=1dyrqu) to play/test with the data.

Here are some commented queries. Let me know which most closely meets your needs. (ordered by relevance)

```
// Match the query target, and everyone who can endorse
MATCH (target:User{name:"Ben"}), (person:User),

// Match all endorse chains, length limit 5 
p=((person)-[:TRUSTS*..5]->(target)) 

// Our target may start, and will end; our chain, so no other path nodes can be him. 
// Normal matching will not match cycles.
// Adjust further path termination conditions here.
WHERE ALL(n in NODES(p)[1..-1] WHERE n<>target) 

//  Return target (extra), the 1'st tier endorser, their endorsers, and rank(depth) of each of those endorsers.
RETURN target.name, NODES(p)[-2] as endorser, COLLECT(person.name), SIZE(RELATIONSHIPS(p)) as depth 
ORDER BY depth

// one line copy for copy-paste into console
MATCH (target:User{name:"Ben"}), (person:User), p=((person)-[:TRUSTS*..5]->(target)) WHERE ALL(n in NODES(p)[1..-1] WHERE n<>target) RETURN target.name, NODES(p)[-2] as endorser, COLLECT(person.name), SIZE(RELATIONSHIPS(p)) as depth ORDER BY depth
```

An alternate return format

```
WITH NODES(p)[-2] as endorser, {people:COLLECT(person.name), depth:SIZE(RELATIONSHIPS(p))} as auth 
RETURN endorser, COLLECT(auth)

// one line copy for copy-paste into console
MATCH (target:User{name:"Ben"}), (person:User), p=((person)-[:TRUSTS*..5]->(target)) WHERE ALL(n in NODES(p)[1..-1] WHERE n<>target) WITH NODES(p)[-2] as endorser, {people:COLLECT(person.name), depth:SIZE(RELATIONSHIPS(p))} as auth RETURN endorser, COLLECT(auth)
```

UPDATE: Alternate return format to match OP's return table

```
MATCH (target:User{name:"Rus"}), (person:User), p=((person)-[:TRUSTS*]->(target)) WHERE ALL(n in NODES(p)[1..-1] WHERE n<>target) WITH NODES(p) as n, SIZE(RELATIONSHIPS(p)) as depth RETURN DISTINCT n[-depth] as parent, n[-depth-1] as child, depth ORDER BY depth
```

Comment: I've just taken a more indepth look, and it looks like it's not exactly right. Using the first query, it's perfect up to `depth <= 2`, but at `depth > 2` , the endorser column is incorrect.

The endorser column should, at each depth, list the endorsers of each user in `COLLECT(person.name)` column. E.g. at `depth = 3`, the endorser column has `Ben`, & `JM`, but should have `JM`, `Simon` & `Rus` (the three users from the previous depth)

Comment: I think the issue is with `NODES(p)[-2] as endorser`, instead of being fixed at `-2`, I believe it should decrease as the relationship depth increases?

Comment: @BenedictLewis Can you add a table to your question showing exactly what you want returned by the query?

Comment: cheers, I've updated the question with a table example and more in depth details on the issue (see below the dividing line)

Comment: @BenedictLewis Added new return format. (your example table missed ben->robbie->rus) Also looking at your other question, what is the diffrence between the answer to this question and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46604460/produce-tree-from-relationship-structure)?

Comment: cheers, the question was the same, I was trying to reword it a bit more clearly but your reply has resolved my issue

Comment: @BenedictLewis One other thing. For ranking, you could calculate it as `rep=(SUM(incoming_rep+1)/(SUM(incoming_rep)+10))`. This will give you a number between 0 and 1 that looks like [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(n%2B1)%2F(n%2B10)+for+n+from+0+to+100). Because this calculation is recursive though, Cypher hates it so I don't know how to build it directly into the query. Maybe in another question, someone could figure out how to make Cypher do that in a way that won't kill performance.